# About the meaning of the bold part?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> It is interesting that when we are introduced to books as sources of
>   information in our childhood it does not usually go like that. We are
>   taught to consult books like oracles, and the idea of the author is
>   not much brought to our attention at first. In any case, after a time
>   we come to receive communications in books without anyone introducing
>   them to us, and we are apt to believe—**as we put it**—what the book
>   says about itself; for example that it was printed by a certain
>   printer.

I know the meaning of "put", and "as we put it". But I want to know where "it" refers to. Does it mean "as we say"? As we say what? That we are apt to believe? But do we say such a thing? Or we *may* say so? So shouldn't it be "as we may put it"? Moreover, to what does "we" refer? To human beings? Or to we who are discussing here?

Comment: The passage discusses the meaning of "believe". The bold part refers to the preceding word "believe" in "we are apt to believe". You could read it as *"... and we are apt to believe—in the sense we are discussing—what the book says about itself"*.

Answer (score 1):

> and we are apt to believe**—as we put it—**what the book says about itself

My take is that the parenthetical phrase refers to what comes *after* it, rather than to anything that comes before it.

Consider phrases like these:

> **With all due respect,** I have to disagree.
>   It is, **for lack of a better word**, ungracious.
>   My child is**—if you'll forgive the term—** a brat.

In each case, the interjection relates to what follows it, not what precedes it.

In this passage, *what the book says about itself* is a strange turn of phrase for anybody who doesn't use it. Books don't normally talk about themselves. Instead, we *interpret* what we read and see in them. (In the example given in this case, that it was printed on a certain printer.)

So, the author uses *as we put it* to mean that *what the book says about itself* is just a figure of speech that we (people) sometimes use, and not something to be taken literally.

Comment: Do you still think so? https://books.google.com/books?id=hX27BAAAQBAJ&pg=PT27&dq=%22We+are+taught+to+consult+books+like+oracles,+and+the+idea+of+the+author+is+not+much+brought+to+our+attention+at+first.&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxhqfivbrfAhUJM-wKHQRFDioQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22We%20are%20taught%20to%20consult%20books%20like%20oracles%2C%20and%20the%20idea%20of%20the%20author%20is%20not%20much%20brought%20to%20our%20attention%20at%20first.&f=false